# How to add global funtions like Create, Methods, Mounted from a plugin in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

For some cases, I don't want to use `mixins` in my Plugin.
I am trying to add a custom Methods like `created()`, `mounted()`, `methods{}`, so I can access its property when the component is loaded & run my custom method.
example: "customMethod"

```js
// @root/home.vue

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  mounted(){
    //
  },
  methods{
    //
  },
  customMethod{
    
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Vould you clarify and e.g provide an example?

Comment: you can see in the code , i want to add "customMethod" like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.vue file

```
<script>
export default {
 customMethod () { // Custom option.
  console.log('custom method executed!')
 },
 methods: {},
 created () {},
 mounted () {}
}
</script>
```

plugins/customMethods.js

```
const customMethods = {
  install (Vue) {
    // INSTALL
    if (this.installed) return
    this.installed = true

    Vue.options = Vue.util.mergeOptions(Vue.options, {
     created: function () {
      if (this.$options.customMethod) { // If found in the component.
       this.$options.customMethod() // Execute the customMethod.
      }
     }
    })
  }
}

export default customMethods
```

main.js

```
import customMethods from 'plugins/customMethods.js'
Vue.use(customMethods)
```

> What this does is extend the default options for all Vue instances so
>   the behavior is applied to every single Vue instance created. This is
>   however undocumented at the moment.

*Alternatively, this can also be achieved by the use of global mixin in the plugin. (which you don't want for some reason as per your use case.)*

Moreover, one advanced use case is we may need special handling when merging custom option values during `Vue.extend`. For example, the `created` hook has a special merge strategy that merges multiple hook functions into an Array so that all of them will be called. The default strategy is a simple overwrite. If you need a custom merge strategy you will need to register it under `Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies`:

```
Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.customMethod = function (parentVal, childVal) {
  // return merged value.
}
```

Comment: awesome. worked perfectly.
can you give me any link where I can find more about this API?

Answer (score 0):

Every component can access your `customMethod` if you inject it into `Vue.prototype` like this:

```js
Vue.prototype.customMethod = function() {}
```

Comment: if we do like your solution then I can't use methods as I have shown there.
as per your solution, i can only access the customMethod bt this.customMethod not like an object as in example